# make error, gcc: "make[4]: gcc: permission denied" (Arch Linux)

Tags: r, linux, gcc, makefile, archlinux

I encountered a rather strange `make` error when trying to compile some packages. I am running Arch Linux 5.6.7

For instance, when trying to compile R 3.6, I get the following error (full output at the end):

```
gcc -shared -fopenmp -L/usr/local/lib64 -o libRblas.so blas.o  cmplxblas.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath
make[4]: gcc: Permission denied
```

However `gcc` is up-to-date, worked for other installs, and everything seems correctly configured:

```
[cmasso6@cmasso6 R-3.6.3]$ gcc --version
gcc (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[cmasso6@cmasso6 R-3.6.3]$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

I took a look at the *Makeconf* file of the package, which contains the following line: `CC=gcc`. Changing it to `CC=/usr/bin/gcc` made it work.

Here is my `$PATH`:

```
/usr/lib/aurutils:/usr/lib:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Again, `gcc` runs correctly from the command line. I don't know what is going on.

To be clear, I made this install work by changing the *Makeconf* file, and I can also install R 4.0 with `pacman` without any trouble. However, I get the same error when trying to install some R packages, like `ps`. So I guess there is a general issue with `gcc` and/or `make`.

I have no idea what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated!

The full output of the `make` error:

```
[cmasso6@cmasso6 R-3.6.3]$ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/m4'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'R'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/m4'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/tools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'R'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/tools'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/doc/html'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/doc/html'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/doc/manual'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'R'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/doc/manual'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/doc'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/etc'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/etc'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/share'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/share'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/scripts'
creating src/scripts/R.fe
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/scripts'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/scripts'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/scripts'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/include'
config.status: creating src/include/config.h
config.status: src/include/config.h is unchanged
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/include/R_ext'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/include/R_ext'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/include'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/extra'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/extra/blas'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/extra/blas'
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fpic  -g -O2  -c blas.f -o blas.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fpic  -g -O2  -c cmplxblas.f -o cmplxblas.o
gcc -shared -fopenmp -L/usr/local/lib64 -o libRblas.so blas.o  cmplxblas.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath
make[4]: gcc: Permission denied
make[4]: *** [Makefile:37: libRblas.so] Error 127
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/extra/blas'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:32: R] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/extra/blas'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:35: make.blas] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src/extra'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:28: R] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cmasso6/Downloads/R-3.6.3/src'
make: *** [Makefile:61: R] Error 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a directory named `gcc` somewhere in one of the directories in your `PATH`, before the one that contains the `gcc` binary.

This is a bug in a module in the GNU gnulib library, that GNU make uses to locate content on the PATH.  See https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?57962

Comment: Wow, great catch @MadScientist